# workflows to update data in IMIS enterprise cloud

Tags: crm

I am new to IMIS which is an Engagement management system with membership handling inbuilt. I need some inputs about the business process automation in IMIS. I see IMIS does not allow creating stored procedures to clients using IMIS cloud hosting. This seems to be a concern as every business has simple to complex processes and many processes updates data too. I am surprised to see that IMIS does not have a proper workflow builder (GUI based) where one can select as if some Business object is updated/created or have some value X then "**update**" some other business object/**data** i.e **update the database table with specific values**.

Best example if I want to use a custom Membership numbers (autonumbers) then I cannot do that. I cannot update table data via IMIS "process automation". IMIS "process builder"  offers very limited functionality. It do allows calling stored procedure via it but what is the use of it as we cannot create a stored procedure in IMIS. IMIS does allow calling 3rd party REST api via process automation too for particular trigger. With in IMIS there is no way to add custom code handling or custom process handling or a UI based workflow with if/else (a BPM which is available in Salesforce, Zoho and other CRM).

SO I want to know if there is any IMIS consultant here then please guide me how do you suggest handling complex business process automations ? I know IMIS allows REST API but that means I need to write a custom code to handle the process automation and it also means I need to do it outside of IMIS cloud. I just need a confirmation that business process need to be handled via customization outside IMIS through an external system. The external system will get data from IMIS, make the data changes and push it back to IMIS via API. I can build it but before doing so I am trying to make sure I am not missing something which is inside in IMIS (99% sure it cannot be done inside IMIS)

I also believe IMIS does not have webhooks as well as there is no menu to configure the same in IMIS. Please guide on this.

Please do not point me back to "process automation" menu or feature of IMIS as I am aware of it and its limitation too. I have explained its limitation above after checking with the IMIS support desk.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't do complex workflows in iMIS cloud (yet, as of July 2022). No web hooks either. Both of these requirements can be covered with a cloud based RPA solution.

Comment: Thanks Nick. IMIS has sold their system to our team by telling it is highly customizable and an alternative of Salesforce. As per my findings one wil need to build a custom app  which will interact with IMIS through API(pull or push data) but in absence of the webhooks even such custom program will never be effective. There are some prebuilt custom programs being sold by related parties, providers of IMIS but again that means a customization is needed then I will prefer to build the custom app in salesforce itself rather than building an custom app out of IMIS (considering data security issue)